# How to solve Absolute Value abs() objective with Python Gekko?

Tags: python, numpy, mathematical-optimization, ipopt, gekko

An optimization problem with a squared objective solves successfully with IPOPT in Python Gekko.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(); y = m.Param(3.2)
m.Obj((x-y)**2)
m.solve()
print(x.value[0],y.value[0])
```

However, when I switch to an absolute value objective `np.abs(x-y)` (the numpy version of `abs`) or `m.abs(x-y)` (the Gekko version of `abs`), the IPOPT solver reports a failed solution. An absolute value approximation `m.sqrt((x-y)**2)` also fails.

**Failed Solution**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(); y = m.Param(3.2)
m.Obj(m.abs(x-y))
m.solve()
print(x.value[0],y.value[0])
```

I understand that gradient-based solvers don't like functions without continuous first and second derivatives so I suspect that this is happening with `abs()` where `0` is a point that does not have continuous derivatives. Is there any alternative to `abs()` to reliably solve an absolute value with gradient-based solvers in Python Gekko?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use m.abs2 instead, It takes into account the issue with the derivative and should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one possible solution using gekko's binary switch variable:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
y = m.Param(3.2)
x = m.Var()
#intermediate
difference = m.Intermediate(x - y)

f = m.if3(difference, -difference, difference)

m.Obj(f)
m.solve()
print(x.value[0],y.value[0])
```

Returns: 3.2 3.2

`m.if3(condition, x1, x2)` takes value as a condition, and returns `x1` if `condition >= 0` or `x1` if `condition < 0`.

There are various functions to get around this problem in the logical functions section of the documentation, including `m.abs2`, `m.abs3`, and `m.if2`.

The type 2 functions use MPCC to solve and will continue using IPOPT. The type 3 functions will change to APOPT automatically.

https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/blob/master/docs/model_methods.rst
https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html#logical-functions

Comment: That's an interesting approach with the `if3` statement. Thanks for the documentation links - they really help. It looks like `m.abs2` or `m.abs3` are what I need.