# Occurrence of 0 while using m.abs3()

Tags: gekko

The use of m.abs3() gives result value as 0 for initial value while using in a time series analysis. This further causes 'division by 0' problem in the subsequent calculations.

In the script, for example, for values of `x = [-0.010292872139, -0.013621207394, -0.013666766692, -0.013712305714, -0.013757829097, -0.013803253697, -0.013848595166, -0.013893769488, -0.013943077385, -0.013987013738, -0.014030702679]`, m.abs3(x) returns `[0.0, 0.013621207394, 0.013666766692, 0.013712305714, 0.013757829097, 0.013803253697, 0.013848595166, 0.013893769488, 0.013943077385, 0.013987013738, 0.014030702679]` as result.

I have tried m.if3(x,-x,x) as a work around as suggested here - [How to solve Absolute Value abs() objective with Python Gekko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58646404/how-to-solve-absolute-value-abs-objective-with-python-gekko) but the result is still the same as above for m.abs3(x).

Could you please let me know what causes this to occur and is there a way to solve this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a lower bound to the value of x solved the problem; m.x.LOWER = 10**-10

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to change the initial guess for `y` to be something other than the default of `0`. Here is an example script that shows how to initialize `y` to 1 with `y.value=1`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Param(-1)
y = m.abs3(x)

# initialize y to value 1
y.value = 1

m.Minimize((x/y)**2)
m.solve()
```